# Cryptostylite - appearance and usage?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

I've been very interested in this word for a couple of decades, and I keep waiting for it to appear in English, but I can't find any uses.  Has anyone come across this word?  The closest I can find is "[cryptostylis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptostylis)".

---

Part of the impetus for this question is I'm using it in my profile, and concerned people may not take the meaning.  I interpret it as: (1) a person who uses technology to separate themselves from the material world; (2) a computer nerd; (3) one who uses technology to remain hidden from the world, i.e. "[blackhats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hat)".

*I'm certainly not using it in a pejorative sense, though my assumption is it would be taken that way by non-techs.*

The medieval [stylites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylite) were [ascetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asceticism) who famously sat on pillar in pursuit of spiritual goals.  In the post-computing era, these goals become technological.

Comment: Some people might appreciate your _nonce word_ (which won't be a true word according to some definitions). But why would people assume that the goals of stylites had switched from spiritual ones to technological? The answer below doesn't demand that reading. Many people might not appreciate your nonce word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I appreciate your input.  Although I don't think there are many active stylites in the modern world, crypto is used to connote computing in the sense of encoding information for procedural purposes.

Comment: But deciding to push productivity by prefixing an accepted word with crypto- is an English not a computing device. You haven't found 'Cryptostylite' (with or without a hyphen) in 20 years. I haven't found it. You're worried that  people may not take a meaning you'd like for a word you're making up, which meaning doesn't correspond with the normal rules of word formation. I'll have to close-vote as off-topic.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. 'Is this in the lexicon, and if so does it have meaning ...?' might work.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You make fair points.  I accept that there is probably no current usage. (Part of the question was to determine that, as one cannot entirely trust web search, thus my coming to the English language experts.)

Comment: @TimLymington Honestly, my intent was to determine if anyone had come across the term before.  I incorporated "cryptostylis" to relate it to a "real
 word in current use. I appreciate the input!

Comment: The word you might be looking for is [Introvert](http://www.myersbriggs.org/my-mbti-personality-type/mbti-basics/extraversion-or-introversion.htm).  See for example [How Technology and Social Media Empower the Introvert](http://knowledge-leader.colliers.com/editor/how-technology-and-social-media-empower-the-introvert/).  Very few people (well, one at least) would interpret *cryptostlist* to mean the 3 part definition that you gave.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Thanks for that link to that article.  Definitely the right idea.  I get your point about the subtler meanings, which require a fairly fundamental understanding of computing and "encoding", and agree that the common usage of crypto refers to secrecy, and that this factor injects a certain fuzziness. *(Don't even get me started on "Algorithmic Intelligence" vs. "Artificial Intelligence", both correct, but the former providing a more meaningful definition from a procedural perspective;)*

Answer (score 1):

[Crypto-](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/crypto-) is a combining form so it is legitimate to prefix it to other words. The "o" is the [combining vowel](http://emp.byui.edu/pearsonf/lesson1.htm).  Medical terms make much use of  combining forms. So if you want to be a secret stylite then have at it.

Comment: Nice.  I beleive crypto may have a wider meaning than the formal definition in that "information technologies" are "syntactic systems", in the sense that all computer instructions are a form of "code".  "Encoding" is widely used in a sense that does not imply subterfuge.

Comment: Some would consider that [poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetry) :-)

Comment: Thanks!  I also want to add that the meaning you propose is also correct, in that a subset of "crypostylites" do use the information technologies to remain hidden, generally what are known as "[blackhats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hat)", so I very much appreciate your analysis. :)

Comment: @DukeZhou ELU deals with established usage in English. Your question is miles away from that.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth he is just having fun with the English language. I wish more people would. And his question, viewed as a question on combining forms, strikes me as legitimate. But I am new here so I will defer to your greater experience.

Comment: But someone may read this, think that the word _is_ in the lexicon, use it in their CV with the meaning OP would like the candidate word to have, and be rejected. The big advantage ELU has over many English websites is a degree of trustworthiness. There are many places where one can have fun with the English language without misleading people. 'DIY English' is against the ethos of the site.

Comment: @edwinAshworth I doubt that many readers would make the stretch from "secret stylite" to "computer blackhat" based on this Q&A.  DukeZhou as much as stated that his motivation is poetry. Proper English usage goes as far as "secret stylite" and that was my answer.

Comment: I wanted to thank you again for focusing me on the "hidden" origin of kruptos.  It's the same root as crypt, which indicates something beneath the surface, but not necessarily "secret".  I don't find this to be in conflict with my understanding of cryptostylite in that it the folks I'm talking about generally use "handles" instead of their real names.  My feeling on words such as cryptofascist is that they are apt but archaic in the sense that I don't think one can meaningfully separate *crypto* from computing after ~1940, thus computing is strongly implied.